# Namespace issue in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have two files Sample.cpp and Main_file.cpp. Sample.cpp has only one namespace `n1` which contains the definition of `int` variable `x`. I want to print this variable `x` in my main_file.cpp. How do I go about doing this?

```
//Sample.cpp_BEGINS

namespace n1
{
    int x=10;
}
//Sample.cpp_ENDS

//Main_FILE_BEGINS

void main()
{
    print x;
}
//MAIN_FILE_ENDS
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the fully qualified name of the variable:

```
int main()
{   
     n1::x = 10;

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: when i tried the aforesaid code, I got the following 2 errors:

1) 'n1' : is not a class or namespace name. 
2) 'x' : undeclared identifier.

Comment: @user1168582: Did you include the header file which actually defined the namespace to `main.cpp`? Unless you include that the compiler won't really know what is `n`.

Comment: I dont have any header file in this case. I have defined the namespace in Sample.cpp file. And trying to access integer variable x into main() method

Comment: @user1168582: Some of the answers have already answered your modified Q in the comments, while I was away so I will not repeat the same.However,Why are you trying to simple things in a complicated/Unconventional manner if I may ask?

Answer (score 5):

To make `n1::x` accessible from main.cpp you'll probably want to create and include `sample.h`:

```
// sample.h
#ifndef SAMPLE_H
#define SAMPLE_H

namespace n1
{
    extern int x;
}
#endif
```

---

```
// sample.cpp
#include "sample.h"

namespace n1
{
    int x = 42;
}
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sample.h"

int main()
{   
     std::cout << "n1::x is " << n1::x;
}
```

If you prefer not to create a header file you can also do this in your main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace n1
{
    extern int x;
}    

int main()
{   
     std::cout << "n1::x is " << n1::x;
}
```

Comment: But I dont want to create Sample.h file.  I wanted only one Sample.cpp file and one main.cpp file.

Comment: @user1168582 you can just put `n1::x`'s declaration right in main.cpp in that case. See my edited example.

Answer (score 4):

add a line `using namespace n1` in main or you can also do as @als suggested.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using the `using declaration` but if the namespace being imported contains a lot of symbols then it is always better to use full qualification rather than polluting the current namespace with all symbols from the namespace being imported.

Comment: @als ..you are right...but i just thought of solving the OP's problem :)

Comment: @Als : `using declaration` is completely different from `using directive`. This answer talks about the latter and not the former.

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav:Indeed, this is `using directive` not `using declaration`. I stand corrected on the typo.And Ofcourse, My comment here applies to `using directive` and not `using declaration`.

Answer (score 3):

From your comment, it seems that you want only 2 `.cpp` files. In that case, following will do the job:

```
//Sample.cpp_BEGINS
namespace n1
{
  int x=10;
}
//Sample.cpp_ENDS

//Main_FILE_BEGINS
namespace n1
{
  extern int x;   // <---- mention that `x` is defined in other .cpp file
}
void main()
{
  print n1::x;  // to avoid 'n1::', mention 'using namespace n1;` above
}
//MAIN_FILE_ENDS
```